# How to compile TypeScript to JavaScript into a different folder

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, tsc

I have two folders: TypeScript and JavaScript. I need to compile the TypeScript file which are in TypeScript folder to JavaScript files in the JavaScript folder.

Comment: Use the building tool of your preference. (grunt, gulp, ...)

Comment: @Shilly Thanks alot :D

Comment: The way to do this is to read the manual. Or you could google "typescript target directory". Or you could search SO for answers like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454371/typescript-how-to-keep-compiled-files-in-a-separate-directory).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`--outDir   string      Redirect output structure to the directory.`

[tsconfig reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: Thanks it worked :D

Answer (score -1):

Add a tsConfig.json file to the root of your TypeScript project. One option to the compiler is `outDir` which specifies the output directory. See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./JavaScript"
    },
    "files": ["./TypeScript/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Comment: tsConfig.json file must be present in the typescript folder ?

Comment: @an0nh4x0r It should be in the root of your TypeScript project. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html