# How to let Firebase functions find index.js from another directory?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using firebase functions with typescript similar to [this instruction](https://github.com/ultrasaurus/firebase-functions-typescript). However, I want to keep all tsc compilation result in a separate build folder, so after `tsc` my project folder look like this:

```
myApp
 |__ functions
      |__ src/index.ts
      |__ build/src/index.js
```

How can I let firebase find `build/src/index.js` instead of `./index.js`? There doesn't seem to be a firebase deploy option for this.

Currently I have to `cp build/src/index.js .` in my npm scripts but it feels like a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THere's currently no option to specify a different output folder for Functions, like you can for Hosting. So instead of this, you probably need to put your .ts files into a different folder (e.g. `myApp/functions_src`) and tell tsc to output the compiled versions into `myApp/functions` by using `--outdir ./functions` as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454371/typescript-how-to-keep-compiled-files-in-a-separate-directory).

Answer (score 4):

By default, Firebase looks in the `functions/` folder for the source code but you can specify another folder by adding the following lines in `firebase.json`:

```
"functions": {
  "source": "another-folder"
}
```

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions

Answer (score 2):

Firebase actually uses the `main` field from your `functions/package.json` file, you just have to update it with the correct compiled path:

```
{
  "main": "build/src/index.js"
}
```