# TypeScript API for compiling in a different directory

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a typescript program that contains multiple `.ts` files.
I want to compile those `.ts` to `.js` and place them in a different directory.

I'm inspired by the example from this page: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API

```
function compile(fileNames, options) {
    let program = ts.createProgram(fileNames, options);
    let emitResult = program.emit();

    let allDiagnostics = ts
        .getPreEmitDiagnostics(program)
        .concat(emitResult.diagnostics);

    allDiagnostics.forEach(diagnostic => {
        if (diagnostic.file) {
            let {line, character} = diagnostic.file.getLineAndCharacterOfPosition(
                diagnostic.start
            );
            let message = ts.flattenDiagnosticMessageText(
                diagnostic.messageText,
                "\n"
            );
            console.log(
                `${diagnostic.file.fileName} (${line + 1},${character + 1}): ${message}`
            );
        } else {
            console.log(
                `${ts.flattenDiagnosticMessageText(diagnostic.messageText, "\n")}`
            );
        }
    });

    let exitCode = emitResult.emitSkipped ? 1 : 0;
    console.log(`Process exiting with code '${exitCode}'.`);
    process.exit(exitCode);
}
```

Then I use `outDir` in compiler options object

```
compile(["test.ts"], {
    noEmitOnError: false,
    noImplicitAny: false,
    target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES5,
    module: ts.ModuleKind.ESNext,
    outDir: "output" // files are placed in a directory called output
});
```

It works, however I'm curious if there's a different way to decide the location where to write the `.js` files that doesn't involve `outDir` property from compiler options.

**Note:** I'm looking for an answer that uses the typescript api and not the command line `tsc`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the Typescript compiler to output the compiled js to a different directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454371/how-can-i-get-the-typescript-compiler-to-output-the-compiled-js-to-a-different-d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument for `emit()` is `writeFile?: WriteFileCallback`. You can try to use it and implement writing files yourself in whatever way you need:

```
program.emit(undefined, yourOwnWriteFileFunction);
```

Also, according to comments and the code, `ts.createProgram()` accepts custom implementation for [`CompilerHost`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9bd23652ef8c4e6a614a2f27c467b1a68ce3340e/src/compiler/types.ts#L4997) which also can override `writeFile`:

```
export interface CompilerHost extends ModuleResolutionHost {
    ....
    writeFile: WriteFileCallback;
```

[Relevant part of `Program` interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9bd23652ef8c4e6a614a2f27c467b1a68ce3340e/src/compiler/types.ts#L2873)

```
export interface Program extends ScriptReferenceHost {

    /**
     * Emits the JavaScript and declaration files.  If targetSourceFile is not specified, then
     * the JavaScript and declaration files will be produced for all the files in this program.
     * If targetSourceFile is specified, then only the JavaScript and declaration for that
     * specific file will be generated.
     *
     * If writeFile is not specified then the writeFile callback from the compiler host will be
     * used for writing the JavaScript and declaration files.  Otherwise, the writeFile parameter
     * will be invoked when writing the JavaScript and declaration files.
     */
    emit(targetSourceFile?: SourceFile, writeFile?: WriteFileCallback, cancellationToken?: CancellationToken, emitOnlyDtsFiles?: boolean, customTransformers?: CustomTransformers): EmitResult;
```

Note that these parts of API are not documented on the TypeScript wiki, so if you decide to use them you should keep an eye on [breaking API changes page](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/API-Breaking-Changes).