# Compile on save in tsconfig.json works differently for new files than it does for existing files

Tags: angular, tsconfig, outdir

So I've been experimenting around with Angular lately and its features. One of them is the `CompileOnSave` feature in the `tsconfig.json` with the following settings:

```
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"watch":  true,
```

This all works, however, I'm seeing different behavior between adding new files and modifying existing files. In both cases, file modifications get compiled to the `./dist/out-tsc` folder. All good. However, when adding a new file the compiler also generates a .js file and its corresponding map file in the same folder. This is confusing. Is this by design? And should I delete them manually or can this be automated? My question is similar to

[How can I get the Typescript compiler to output the compiled js to a different directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454371/typescript-how-to-keep-compiled-files-in-a-separate-directory)

however, I already have the `outDir` property configured. I am using Visual Studio 2019. Please see the screenshot below from a part of the project directory. `api.component.ts` is an existing file which modifications are compiled to the `./dist/out-tsc` directory. `file.ts`, `file1.ts` and `file2.ts` are new files which seem to be compiled to the folder they are created in, as well as to the `./dist-out-tsc` folder. My Angular version is 8.3.14.

[screenprint from visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHvVQ.jpg)

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "watch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding this to my .csproj file. I want to emphasize however, that compile on save was already turned OFF in Visual Studio and visual studio restarted. That's why I was thrown off guard. Guess this wasn't enough.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>False</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
</PropertyGroup>
```